# Dell display manager PBP split

Tags: display, dell

Is it possible to split dell monitor NOT into 50/50% when using two inputs and PBP mode but split it in 60/40 or 70/30
Dell display manager allows only 50/50 but maybe it is possible with ddm.exe?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: why are you using the `multiple-monitors` tag, when you are asking about only one monitor?

Answer (score 0):

The U3821DW supported PBP screen splits are shown in the online
[U3821DW User's Guide](https://dl.dell.com/content/manual29771593-dell-u3821dw-monitor-user-s-guide.pdf) page 50.

The only splits available are :

- 50% - 50%
- 67% - 33%
- 33% - 67%

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i have U4323QE and unfortunately 33/67 or 67/33 is not available

Comment: Wild idea : Transplant the splits from the U3821DW software into your setup. But I don't have the setup to find out how to implement it.